# Mobile website text is messed up on Android devices

Tags: android, mobile-website

The text on my mobile site is "squishing" to the left. The rest of the site fills the page as intended. The text is wrapped in div elements, but it doesn't matter if I put them in divs or paragraphs, the outcome is the same. When I set a height on each element, it corrects the problem, but I'm trying to avoid that since there are a lot of paragraphs and they are all different sizes, not to mention future usability.

[Here is](http://m.charleskrug.com/1861.php) an example and a screenshot:

[image]

On ALL the text elements, this happens, whether it's a ul, div, p, or header tags...

Also, it appears fine on older Androids and iPhones...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks fine on my Galaxy Nexus (4.1.2). Can you maybe upload a screenshot of a "bad" render?

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen! =P Now, seriously, does that happen in your phone only? or in the emulator as well?

Comment: Just the Android phones... it happened on 3 different Android phones. It won't let me upload a photo since I'm a new user :( But I did add it at http://m.charleskrug.com/images/screenshot.png

Comment: I am not sure but you could try using twitter boot-strap to design your web-pages. It has all the css you need to display your web-pages accurately on all screen sizes.. (any screen). Its very simple to use.

Comment: I used it for my app wherin I have standalone html pages and they look neat on all android devices...

Comment: I would have LOVED to use Twitter Bootstrap, but due to the design, it wasn't very plausible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I didn't set the "initial-scale" in the name="viewport" tag in the head tags.

The final tag that resolved the issue is

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=630px; height=device-height; initial-scale=0.5;" />
```

Thanks for all the input!